# combining 2 sql queries based on different conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have a table :

**Person :**

```
(integer) (varchar)  (Date)         (date)
  id       state       d1            d2  
  1       'ALIVE'   '2015-08-07'  '2015-08-08'
  2       'DEAD'    '2015-08-08'  '2015-08-10'
  3       'DEAD'    '2015-08-08'  '2015-08-08'
```

And so on..

What I want is the count of all people when :

> 1. person is alive and d1 <=someDate
> 2. person is dead and d2 > someDate and d1 < = someDate.

So, in the above case, if someDate = '2015-08-08', then the output should be 2. i.e, id `3` should not be considered.

I can of course do this as 2 seperate queries and add the result. How to do this in just one query.

Note : This is an example of what I am trying to do. The table names, columns are different in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple `OR` condition:

```
select *
from person
where (state = 'ALIVE' and d1 <= DATE '2015-08-08')
   or (state = 'DEAD' and d2 > DATE '2015-08-08');
```

The parentheses combining the `AND` operators are required, otherwise you'd get a wrong result.